# edit config of tailwind does not work as expected

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind with Laravel.

In HTML:

```html
<h1 class="text-primary-700"> the text </h1>
```

I have edited `tailwind.config.js` to be

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: '#ccc',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

But the color did not change to `#CCC`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any command I do have to run to apply the changes in the config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thint it should be like this

```
'primary': {
      50: '#1976dd',
      100: 'add color here',
      200: 'add color here',
      ...
      900: 'add color here',
      DEFAULT: '#ccc',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this config structure

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      'white': '#ffffff',
      'purple': '#3f3cbb',
      'midnight': '#121063',
       DEFAULT: '#ccc',
    },
  },
}
```